# Running .m file from Mathematica notebook

Tags: evaluation

I have use the following command to save a table called "matrix_name" as a .m file named "matrix.m":

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
Save["matrix.m", matrix_name]
```

After this file is created, I try to run it from another mathematica notebook using the following command:

```
<< matrix.m;
```

but I get the message

```
Get: Cannot open matrix.m
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Did you change the Directory[] in a meanwhile? Works fine on Win V12.1

Comment: @Kuba Hi, thanks for the comment. No, I didn't change anything. I'm new to this so I didn't know I should've done this. How can I do this?

Comment: No no, you should not, my point was that unless you've done something with Directory[] it should just work. Can you list step by step way to reproduce it starting from a fresh session?